# Geocoding and Credit Usage?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding, arcgis-online, pricing

I've already geocoded a table of address, and I know I use credits for that.  I'm wondering, when I use the Interactive Rematch Tool, am I using credits?

For example: After the initial geocode, I see an address has come up as a tied address.  So I view my address make necessary edits to the address, then match the candidate address that fits best.

Would I use credits doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the rerun address would charge against your account. As you would be re-hitting the services hosted by ESRI this falls into the normal credit-usage.

While there is not specific documentation of this; my personal experience with the ArcGIS Online credits and how they are applied see this as consistent.